# Discrete Math: CLT, expectation and variance of sample means

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Can someone please help me with the final question in of my toturial sheet. I am only able to answer the first part of the question. Thanks

Amy pays £1 to play a game in which she rolls one standard six-sided die.
She loses her pound if the die shows 1, 2, 3 or 4. She gets her pound back
if the die shows 5, and if the result is 6 then Amy gets her pound back and
also receives an additional reward of £2.

Q1: Let $X$ be a random variable that represents Amy’s gain from a single
round of the game (make sure to include the pound she pays to play
the game). Calculate the expected value and the standard deviation of
$X.$

Q2: If Amy plays the game 100 times, what are the expected value and the
standard deviation of her average gain, $\bar X?$ Hint: use the central limit
theorem.

Q3： If Amy plays the game 100 times, what is the probability that her average gain, $\bar X,$ will be positive? (That is, she walks away with more money
than what she had before playing the game.

Q4： If Amy plays the game 100 times, with probability 0,8997 her average
gain, $\bar X,$ is below what value?

Comment: How about showing us your work towards the answer to the first part. I have given you an outline what to do from there. But if you have questions about it, we could be of more help knowing your approach so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start on (2), assuming you have numerical answers $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from (1) such that $E(X) = \mu$ and $SD(X) = \sigma.$ [I look forward to seeing
your answers to (1) posted at the end of your Question.]

Let $\bar W = \frac 1n(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{n})$ be Amy's average winnings for  $n = 100$ games. Then you must have a formula (in the vicinity of the CLT) that states $E(\bar W) = \mu,\; Var(\bar W) = \sigma^2/n,$ and $SD(\bar W) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

For (3), I suppose you should use the CLT and assume that $\bar W$ has nearly
a normal distribution. Then
$$P(\bar W > 0) = P\left(\frac{\bar W-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} > c\right) \approx P(Z > c) = \,???,$$
where $Z$ is standard normal and you can get a numerical value for
$c = \frac{0-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.$ Then you can use software or printed normal tables to evaluate the probability.

Part (4) is similar to (3), except you need to find $d = \frac{g - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ from printed normal tables such that $P(Z < d) = 0.8997,$
and then solve for $g$.

---

*Notes:* I have a quibble about the statement of the problem:

Strictly speaking the formulas for $E(\bar W)$ and $SD(\bar W)$ are *used*
in the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), but not part of the CLT. The CLT itself states that as $n$ gets
larger, the distribution of $\bar W$ becomes ever more nearly normally distributed. So the CLT is used in (3) but not in (2).

Comment: My answer to the Q(1) is E(X) = -1/3 and SD(x) = √11 /3. Just another question, in the Q(2), the sample mean = population means? and to work out the standard distribution of the population mean we simply apply the formula σ/√n. thank you for your time

Comment: Didn't do (1). may check that later. (2) $E(\bar W) = \mu;$ you're right about $SD(\bar X);$ and you can get $\sigma$ from (1).

Comment: OK, checked (1): Used both direct computation and simulation. $E(X) = -1/3$ and $V(X) = 11/9.$ As you say. Thanks for letting me know your progress. If you edit some work for (1) into your Question, I'll vote to re-open your question. (Who knows with what probability of success.) Might make a difference if you want to use the site again. But best always to have the Question show some engagement on your part.